# Is there any GitLab API call to Get pipeline triggerer name?

Tags: rest, gitlab, gitlab-api

I have to create an automated weekly report by fetching the data using GitLab Api calls. I have to fetch pipeline **triggerer** name for it, but I gone through GitLab docs, but I couldn’t find an API call for it.

This is the GitLab doc link I used to find it [Pipelines API | GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html)

Comment: What do you mean by 'pipeline triggerer name'? username, pipeline source (push event, merge request event, etc), parent pipeline name?